# ANN: Recursive backpropagation

Tags: javascript, recursion, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to implement backpropagation with recursion for academic purposes, but it seems I have gone wrong somewhere. Have been tinkering with it for a while now but either get no learning at all or no learning on the second pattern.

Please let me know where I've gone wrong. (This is javascript syntax)
Note: errors are reset to `null` before every learning cycle.

```
this.backpropagate = function(oAnn, aTargetOutput, nLearningRate) {
    nLearningRate = nLearningRate || 1;

    var oNode, 
        n = 0;

    for (sNodeId in oAnn.getOutputGroup().getNodes()) {
        oNode = oAnn.getOutputGroup().getNodes()[sNodeId];
        oNode.setError(aTargetOutput[n] - oNode.getOutputValue());
        n ++;
    }

    for (sNodeId in oAnn.getInputGroup().getNodes()) {
        this.backpropagateNode(oAnn.getInputGroup().getNodes()[sNodeId], nLearningRate);
    }
}

this.backpropagateNode = function(oNode, nLearningRate) {
    var nError = oNode.getError(),
        oOutputNodes,
        oConn,
        nWeight,
        nOutputError,
        nDerivative = oNode.getOutputValue() * (1 - oNode.getOutputValue()), // Derivative for sigmoid activation funciton
        nInputValue = oNode.getInputValue(),
        n;

    if (nError === null /* Dont do the same node twice */ && oNode.hasOutputs()) {

        nDerivative = nDerivative || 0.000000000000001;
        nInputValue = nInputValue || 0.000000000000001;

        oOutputNodes = oNode.getOutputNodes();

        for (n=0; n<oOutputNodes.length; n++) {
            nOutputError = this.backpropagateNode(oOutputNodes[n], nLearningRate);

            oConn   = oAnn.getConnection(oNode, oOutputNodes[n]);
            nWeight = oConn.getWeight();
            oConn.setWeight(nWeight + nLearningRate * nOutputError * nDerivative * nInputValue);
            nError += nOutputError * nWeight;
        }
        oNode.setError(nError);
    }

    return oNode.getError();
}
```

Comment: How does your neural-net structure look? Is there a reason you're using recursion? You should be able to iterate over individual layers by starting with the output layer and working your way back up.

Comment: Vivin, the academic point of this exercise is to use recursion for BP. (No, this is not my homework, I am just trying to get my mind around this :) The network at this point is very simple: 2-2-1 3-layer network with sigmoid activation functions, that I am trying to train with [1, 0]->[0.2] and [0, 1]->[0.9] training samples.

Comment: Typical algorithms I have seen do this iteratively; I was just wondering why you chose recursion. :)

Comment: You are right, this is not common. The preference for recursion suggested by the data structure. Trees and graphs are easier to grasp from recursive standpoint for me.

Comment: True, if you view a neural network as just a graph of neurons. But then you lose the semantics of "layers", and I think that bit of information is important. But I guess layers are implicitly defined when you look at the outgoing and incoming synapses to a neuron. IMHO it just makes things a little harder. :)

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that recursing down the synapses is less layer-specific then writing a loop per each layer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33102/discussion-between-lex-and-vivin-paliath)

Comment: As a general hint: use finite differences to check your gradient, i.e. the partial derivatives of the error function `E` with respect to the weights and biases. To approximate the gradient numerically for any parameter w you can compute `dE(w)/dw = (E(w+eps) - E(w-eps)) / (2*eps)` where `eps` is a small number (but not too small), e.g. `1e-4`. I can't find any error at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it. Apparently lower-dimensional networks are more likely to get stuck in a local minima. This is easy to grasp knowing that higher-dimensional networks are less likely to achieve any minima, even global.

Implementing momentum that increases with each iteration gets me through most of the minima. So, re-initializing weights to random (-0.5 to 0.5) values and conducting multiple training sessions eventually gets me through all of them.

I am happy to announce that my network now gets through training in 100% of cases if data is classifiable.